# Gaming Stack Exchange swag for top users

Tags: discussion, swag

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Gaming Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- Gaming Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: gaming.stackexchange.com t-shirt]
[image: gaming.stackexchange.com t-shirt closeup]

### The sticker

[image: gaming.stackexchange.com sticker]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store soon as well)</sub>

Comment: Awesome; thanks Jeff & everyone else at SE!

Comment: Very unexpected and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, a great email to start the day. You rock too!

Comment: Wow awesome. I really wish I wasn't on page 3 :)

Comment: While I'm overjoyed at the prospect of swag, I think I should have spent more time revising for my finals...

Comment: MY PARENTS ARE GOING TO KILL ME :( But this is awesome, thanks!

Comment: Wow, yes, very unexpected.  Thanks!

Comment: W00T! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, Jeff! ♪

Comment: Thank you, I'm slowly completing my collection (I have the Area51 and the StackExchange t-shirts already -- I'll start to work on every other site on the network! =o) )

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for being so kind to us... :)

Comment: Sweet!  Keep being awesome Stack Exchange guys!

Comment: I shall wear this during PAX prime with pride

Comment: I guess I will need to get my favicon monogrammed on the back of my awesome new swag!

Comment: Extreme sweetness! Thanks a bunch =D

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I don't know if you or Rebecca got my chat message, but can you replace the Stack Exchange stickers with Super User stickers for me? I don't know if Rebecca already did something for it: I accidentally gave the SE account link instead of SU account link previous time with the election. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you want the user name (e.g. `Nick T`) or the user ID in the form?

Comment: This is so nice.. Thank you guys!

Comment: im on page 3 :(

Comment: Where do we specify the name it should be delivered too? There's no where on the form for it. If a parcel addressed to Macha arrives for me, the person who gets it won't know what to do with it and will give it back to the postman or something. (I'd imagine it's the same for a lot of people using a userrname unrelated to their name too)

Comment: @macha address line 1 is the name

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this form is confusing me. =[

Comment: @gnome you can do this thing!

Comment: serves me right for not reading all meta posts, finally submitted my info today.  awesome

Comment: Lets hope that was the correct way to submit it... :P

Comment: @yx_: Check your e-mail address on your profile and if your anti-spam settings are a bit too aggressive, because we got informed about this by e-mail.

Comment: I feel so loved! :) Just curious, is there a way to know if our info was received successfully? I don't want to rush the queue, just make sure I'm in line!

Comment: Wait. There's a stackexchange store?!

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Out of curiosity, when should we expect these to arrive?

Comment: @shaun 6-8 weeks

Comment: @Jeff Ah - I am graduating in a few days and my address will change, any way to change the shipping address?

Comment: @JeffAtwood :-(

Comment: @fred sorry email the address at the bottom of every page on the site.

Comment: Yay! Got mine today! :)

Comment: Got mine today, wearing it at work :)

Comment: Yay, got my package today – thanks again! :D

Comment: Hurrah, mine just arrived. Didn't have a post code or real name - probably my fault I guess - so lucky it got here, but anyway :D

Comment: Got mine too when I came back from vacation last month! Awesome...

Comment: @JeffAtwood I didn't see this post till now as I am searching for some QA swag.  Any chance at a revival for this? (I am on the 2nd page...) :P

Answer (score 12):

Shirts are progressing!

[image]

Comment: Cool, cool, cool! I *love* the black.

Comment: We should wear these when going to GDC!

Comment: Can't wait to wear this on LAN parties... :)

Answer (score 2):

My stuff arrived a few weeks ago, but the shirt was the wrong size* so I had to let [Ronan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4012/ronan-forman) have it:

[image]

* *Well I did order it for Ronan so technically it wasn't the wrong size*

Comment: nice, awesome :)