# Any plans for G.SE Merch?

Tags: discussion

Stack Exchange and some others sites of the network have some merch of theirs.

I'm wondering, with the lastest raise of Gaming.SE, is there any plans of Gaming.SE Merch?

Also, if there was G.SE Merch, what kinds of merch would you like to see (Shirts, hoddies, etc)?

Comment: If merch starts coming out, the first thing I want to see is a G.SE mouse pad. I really need a new one.

Comment: Thank you for starting this thread. I'm interested in hearing what swag item the community wants besides the standard t-shirts and stickers.

Comment: @Jin Gamer mouse pads would probably be an obvious choice

Comment: This MUST be done!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have t shirts! And Stickers! I have one and a pile of the other!

They aren't sold to the public, but they do get handed out as swag from time to time.

Comment: I need a GSE shirt. I DEMAND one!

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Robots don't wear clothes, silly

Comment: @DaveMcClelland - Irrelevant!

Comment: I could use another GSE shirt...

Answer (score 1):

It seems the old SWAG is still partially available, but not specifically for G.SE.

It was originally handed out by Jeff Atwood himself, which unfortunately he is no longer here. Good designs though.

[You can see the meta here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/gaming-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users)

[and the store here](http://shop.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

How has nobody suggested G.SE hats yet??

Like actual hats, but for real life. ;-)

Comment: Not sure what people have against real life hats... I, for one, would think a baseball cap with a simple logo or badge design (like the shirts) would be awesome.