# Arqade Top User Swag

Tags: discussion, swag

**Update**: packages have all been sent. If you are not living in the USA, your package may take significantly longer to arrive. Your patience is much appreciated! However, if you have any issues or questions about your prize, please direct them to [Katey](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12888/katey-hw), as she will be handling prize fulfillment from now on.

---

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on the top 5 pages of…

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Arqade t-shirt in your size
- Arqade sticker
- Arqade mousepad

As a lot of you probably know, [we already did a round of Top User Swag Packages](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/gaming-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) for Gaming.SE, but that was back when the site was Gaming.SE! Now that the site is Arqade, you clearly need some updated swag! And because this community has grown so much and has been so active lately, we've decided to extend the giveaway to the top 5 pages instead of the top 2 that we normally do.

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences (see sizing guidelines [here](http://www.apparelvideos.com/cs/CatalogBrowser?todo=ss&productId=4980)).

### The t-shirt

[image: arqade-tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: arqade-sticker]

### The mousepad

[image: arqade-mousepad]

Congratulations!

(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on pages 1-5 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)

Comment: Ha ha! I was so close to making the cut-off it's humorous. I'm the 10th user on page SIX. Ah well. Congrats to those with the extra 140 rep I lack. :)

Comment: The blank mothership's a little disconcerting to me for some reason. Either way, thank you, Lauren and Jin!

Comment: @FAE better than people poking you in the chest every time they have a question

Comment: @FAE I agree. I'll tweak it some for the final production.

Comment: Ewwwww round mousepad. Who am I kidding I'll use it anyway.

Comment: \*squeek squeek\* My heretofor padless mouse thanks you.

Comment: Oh awesome. I got my Diablo T-shirt through the post last week and I didn't say thank you! So thanks!

Comment: Many thanks! Can we get an idea of what company is printing the shirts so I can look up a sizing chart?

Comment: You guys are the best.

Comment: Holy crap! Even if I knew you were doing this, I wouldn't expect that *I'd* be included! You guys are awesome.

Comment: What are our choices for size?

Comment: @blem just added a [sizing chart](http://www.apparelvideos.com/cs/CatalogBrowser?todo=ss&productId=4980)

Comment: The swag looks awesome – especially the mousepad; thank you!

Comment: How long until someone makes a real game out of the Arqade logo with mothership as the final boss?

Comment: @Jin If tweaks are allowed, I'll just add that the lack of symmetry is bothering me.  It would be lessened if there was some Gestalt-style grouping going on, and since I think the URL should be there anyways, I'd suggest adding `arqade.com` under the image full-width so everything looks like it's in a block.  If that makes sense.

Comment: @MatthewRead being symmetrical wasn't my concern because I wanted it to look like an actual game screenshot. I also didn't want to put a site url there because I felt it was too "advertisy," especially on a shirt. normally I don't mind, but with this design I feel a URL ruins the mood. Ideally, if you wear this shirt out, your friends will ask you "hey that's a cool shirt, where did you get it?" Then you'd tell them about the awesome arqade.com and its community.

Comment: @Jin I feel like the mothership is too small. The laser is a nice size, but the mothership should be much larger, as it stands it's almost the same size as the arqade ship.

Comment: @MrSmooth I think you're right. the giant laser beam is not the same scale as the one on the site's animated gif. i'll tweak that. also since the mothership doesn't have the "Ask Question" text on it, it looks a bit bare. I'll be adding some detailing to it.

Comment: About when could I expect to receive this? I ask because I will be receiving mail at a different address after about a month from now.

Comment: @Jin Right. A game would have some sort of boundary (game area, window, or at least the screen) so I think it's the lack of such that is making it harder for me to see the image as a screenshot and not ungrouped objects.

Comment: Thanks guys!  Also, how will these be shipped?  I only ask because I may wish to change which address you ship to.  Can you change the address?

Comment: This is great! Thank you for renewing the swag, and Gamers (or Arqaders?) surely love Mousepads.

Comment: @murgatroid99 we normally wait for about 2 weeks for everyone to fill out the spreadsheet with their info, then we send the spreadsheet to our printshop. They handle the shipping. So realistically, shipping should start in about 3 weeks, and another week to get to you. if you want to change your addr later, just email lauren@stackexchange.com with your updated address.

Comment: @MBraedley see my comment to murgatroid99

Comment: @Jin Will the design on the shirt be bigger when it's printed? There's a lot of blank space on the shirt that I feel could benefit from having more color on it. Regardless, thank you to you and Lauren for putting this together!

Comment: @Kotsu yes it will be bigger. it's hard to get the scale right with a fake mockup :)

Comment: @MBraedley have you already filled out the form? If not, it's best to wait until you know your preferred address to do so. There are a lot of recipients for this, so it will be pretty difficult for me to manage changes of address and other requests manually (which is why we're using a form).

Comment: Wow, it came as a total surprise to me to get an email telling me I was getting free stuff... thanks!!! The mouse pad is very cool (and much needed), although I'm going to feel like a total geek wearing that shirt... You don't see many chicks wearing shirts that have lazers and spaceships on them :)

Comment: @Rachel We must travel in vastly different circles ;)

Comment: Colon capital O and colon capital D!

Comment: If feedback on the details is still useful, I'll just say that an 8" *round* mousepad *sounds* a little bit cramped. Us gamers use giant mice fulla buttons and sling them around wildly, y'know :-)

Comment: Wow, this is a really nice surprise!

Comment: What countries will you be able to send the packages to, and is shipping free? Also, is it through postal mail? I don't live in the US.

Comment: @galacticninja - don't worry they post - free - worldwide. I live in the UK and have received several top user swag packages.

Comment: I didn't get the Gaming.SE swag, though I was enlisted and got contacted by the staff. I hope it works this time. Thanks!

Comment: @Bora if you're still waiting for the Diablo t-shirt don't despair, I got today mine, it takes some time to arrive.

Comment: Thank you so much!http://static1.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/Thanks+you+re+pretty+awesome+yourself+_dbd9f27fb55da41aba829f52ca3d010a.jpg

Comment: @Rachel I did not receive an email, should I be concerned?

Comment: @ender I just checked and the email was sent to the address you listed in your user profile. If that's not correct, that could be the problem.

Comment: @Lauren thats very odd, my email address hasnt changed in roughly ten years. It is the same address I that you guys had for when we had the D3 contest as well, and I got those emails...

Comment: @Lauren found it. I'm fail.

Comment: @Lauren I did not receive an email at either of my addresses (changed recently), though I found the old swag one a year too late T_T do you mind resending?

Comment: @Lauren - I still haven't seen or heard anything regarding this after filling out the form, should I be worried yet?

Comment: @Shinrai It took about a month between Lauren sending out Diablo III T-shirt mails, and the shirts actually getting shipped, so if that's anything to go by, I would estimate that this gets shipped during this week or the next. You seem to be in the US, so assuming I've estimated correctly, I wouldn't worry until the end of the month - us non-USians will have to wait longer, but I would still expect most of us will have received it around mid-September (assuming no holdups in customs, etc.).

Comment: @Shinrai (and everyone else who is interested) - no, do not be worried. It takes a long time to get the t-shirts made, and we waited until we had everyone's sizing information to order them. Patience is a virtue :-)

Comment: @Lauren - No impatience, just checking, thanks. :)

Comment: Just got this today, and I have to say they're way cooler than the pictures show (my boyfriend is pretty jealous of my new mousepad). Thank you!!

Comment: I got my package yesterday, thanks!

Comment: I just got my package yesterday as well !! Thanks ! [ Contemplating framing the letter ;) ]

Comment: Got my package yesterday as well! Awesome stuff. Also, @Foxtrot, I was considering the exact same thing. :D Joel Spolsky's signature on it and all...

Comment: +a pen and a felt pen. Thanks! Gaming forever.

Comment: Just got my package.  To say you guys are awesome would be an understatement!

Comment: Wore my shirt the other day to work. Thanks SE!

Comment: Arrived today in Southern Ontario, Canada ... the shirt will debut in front of a class of undergrads Wednesday while I talk to them about communication skills.

Comment: My package arrived safe and sound last Friday just before I left for the long weekend. Thanks muchly!

Comment: My package arrived; thank you again, Stack Exchange!

Comment: Another package successfully went through the german customs and arrived in Saxony, Germany. With an Arqade mothership my Thinkpad feels even more awesome. Thank you for all the stuff <3

Comment: Finally the package arrived in Rome, Italy too! The pen and the sharpie were unexpected, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Besides the items mentioned a the original post, I got a pen and a felt pen (thank you!).

Do you know if that felt pen is good for whiteboards? How about writing on CDs/DVDs? Or only for writing on paper?

I don't want to misuse it, so what's that pen primary use?

(not sure if this should be a comment or an answer)

Comment: It's a sharpie, which means permanent.  Use it for labelling your CD-Rs.  Ha, I crack myself up.  CD-Rs, what are those?

Comment: DON'T write on your whiteboard with it!  If you write on paper, make sure it won't bleed through.  It's very permanent.