# Any possibilities for Arqade swag in the future?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, swag

[The most recent top user swag was back in 2012](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5124/arqade-top-user-swag). Arqade has grown considerably since then, and with it a whole brevy of top quality Q&A. Recently, SE has announced that for both SE and SO they will be having top user swag giveaways. Will Arqade see anymore swag giveaways?

Comment: An Arqade pin would be pretty neat

Comment: I do know that [SE and SO branded swag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back) is coming back, but I don't know about other sites specifically

Comment: I love my Arqade t-shirt. Having something else would be great :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, swag is coming back (see [Swag is coming back!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358195/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange) but it will not feature special Arqade items. This is asked for in [this post by user @Mithical](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358232/295232):

> Are there any per-site swag items (such as t-shirts), or just network and SO?

The [response by @Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back?cb=1#comment1196455_358232), one of the Stack Exchange Community Managers:

> At this point in time, it's just going to be SE and SO. We love the SE sites and their vibrant designs and swag but the overhead of printing and storing the swag for all of the sites really caught up with us and it gets pretty expensive.